# "Drupal-8 Installed already" error while installing

Tags: php, mysql, database, installation, drupal-8

I cannot finish installing drupal-8. I have tried to delete the whole drupal folder and started again but i am facing the same problem.  Please help solve that

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:
You need to change the value in max_allowed_packet = ?
"https://www.drupal.org/node/259580"

Answer (score 0):

You must empty your existing database and replace the settings.php with an unmodified copy.