# Drupal 8 - "Drupal is already installed"

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I try to import an existing Drupal 8 website on my Wampserver, but when I want to access to the backoffice (from /user page) with my id and password, I click on Validate and then I have a page with the message "Drupal is already installed". After that, homepage and other pages are redirected to "Drupal is already installed".
I have to remove the cookie session to be able to access to the website (but impossible to access to the admin).

Has someone already encountered this issue please? I found some solutions on stakoverflow, as increase the max_allowed_packet, but the issue still present.

Thanks a lot for your help!
Regards

Comment: Anyone can help me please?

Comment: We need more info, but you can check this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292456/drupal-already-installed-message-on-restored-site

Comment: check this:~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456829/drupal-8-installed-already-error-while-installing/54634917#54634917

Answer (score 0):

Could also be related to the *post_max_size* in the php.ini. Ran in to similar issues and found [this comment on the same issue on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2840218#comment-13214030), and increasing this value was the solution for me.